# Is this reasoning correct for why sets with the same power set are equal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am wondering whether the following line of reasoning is valid as to conceptually justifying that two sets with the same power set are equal.

1. The element with the greatest cardinality in the power set of *S* is equal to *S*, as this "chooses" to include all the elements of *S* (creating a subset of *S* can be conceptualized as for each element in *S*, choosing to include it in the subset or not). This is the single largest element in the power set, as every other different subset neglects to choose at least one element from *S*.
2. If the power set of *A* and the power set of *B* are the same, then these power sets must have the same largest element. By 1., The element of the greatest cardinality of the former set is *A*, and that of the latter is *B*; therefore *A* = *B*.

Thanks

Comment: @H.sapiensrex I am confused as to why this merely checks whether A is the same size as B: is it not the case that if 2 power sets are the same, for a finite set their largest elements are identical, not merely of the same size?

Comment: You're right, my mistake! I was so focused on the cardinality aspect that I imposed an entirely different interpretation on that condition than what you actually wrote! How embarrassing for me lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warning: there may be multiple elements with greatest cardinality. For example, $\Bbb Z$ has the same cardinality as its subset $\Bbb N$. So picking by cardinality is not the right way to go, it is better to figure things out by which is larger in terms of *containment*. There is only one (for a powerset) maximum element when ordering by inclusion, and these will be the two original sets themselves, so you can argue in this fashion.

I think it's easier just to give the following one-liner, which works for basically the same "reason" but is easier to state correctly:

> Given two sets $A,B$, if $\mathscr{P}(A)=\mathscr{P}(B)$ then: $$A=\bigcup\mathscr{P}(A)=\bigcup\mathscr{P}(B)=B$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I am new to set theory so would appreciate some clarification on what is meant by "ordering by inclusion" and how this differs from ordering by cardinality. @FShrike Also, is it the case that for finite sets, there would be always an element with single greatest cardinality such that the reasoning in my post holds in this limited context?

Comment: @God For finite sets, ordering by cardinality and by inclusion/containment is basically the same thing. For infinite sets it is famously false. Indeed Dedekind *defined* "infinite" as: "is in bijection with a proper subset of itself". Ordering by inclusion means: you say, $A\preceq B$ iff. $A\subseteq B$. Ordering by containment is the dual of this: you say, $A\preceq B$ iff. $B\subseteq A$. Ordering by cardinality would be: $A\preceq B$ iff. $|A|\le|B|$ but I think it requires some work (+ axiom of choice) to say that any two sets are comparable in cardinality.

Comment: @God As for how these differ, well: $\Bbb N$ is a *proper* subset of $\Bbb Z$ but they have the same cardinality. So in $\mathscr{P}(\Bbb Z)$ I have (uncountably many) candidates for a "greatest element" if you order by cardinality, for example $\Bbb N$ would be a greatest element. This ruins your proof idea